# Graduate students funding availability in Pure vs Applied Math

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics, united-states

Universities in the U.S. are sometimes limited in how many students they can accept by the available funding. How does funding compare in Pure vs. Applied departments? Is one generally more funded than the other? Is this less of an issue the higher ranked a university?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most math "funding" in the US is in the form of TA, or, less likely, RA funding. Since TA funding is paid back to the university by participation in assisting (or even teaching) courses, it isn't really a big "expense". Without TAs, lower level courses would need more faculty participation - smaller classes in most places.

So, the number of slots is less determined by some "funding" available than by the sheer size of the department and its need for assistants in lower level (and especially service) classes. Math needs a lot of this since the math department also commonly services most of the rest of the university in its need for some specialized math and maybe statistics courses.

I don't know current statistics, but I'd guess that if a university has separate pure and applied math departments, that the pure math side is bigger, hence more need, hence more slots.

But it also used to be the case that such departments were unified with pure and applied math in one department. In that case, it is immaterial what a student wants to study for the purpose of funding. A TA will still assist in first year courses offered, so the overall size of the department and the number of courses/sections it offers in the lower division is the dominant factor.

And this is independent of the "rank" of a university, though a few top places might have more RA slots that are grant funded rather than coming out of the instructional budget.

---

And, funding in the sense of "come and study here for free with no obligations or duties" is pretty rare.

Comment: I agree that math departments might have more funded slots than applied math departments, but it might be that some applied math departments bring in bigger grants and offer higher stipends.  Though this is just speculation.

Comment: @Kimball It can go either way, but it's roughly true that the top-ranked pure math departments and the top-ranked applied math departments are at different schools.

Comment: Undergraduates students majoring in STEM fields (science, technology, engineering, and mathematics) typically take more required math courses than students in other fields.  At a STEM focused institution you're likely to find a bigger math department (relative to the overall size of the institution) and more teaching assistnat slots.  At institutions without engineering schools you'll see the opposite effect.

Comment: @Kimball  TA/RA funding is often standardized across an institution.  Students in applied math are certainly more likely to get research assistantships, but that doesn't mean that they'll be paid better.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I wonder how common that is.  At my university, there are minimum standards, but the actual grad salaries vary by department (and possibly type of appointment)---I think the pay is highest in engineering or business and probably lowest in the humanities.